# Error while publishing my existing app to the App Store

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting an error while uploading to the App store using XCode. We are able to sign and build the app on a device, but get this error during submission process:

> The following issues were found during Validation:
>
> Exception while validating:- [NSCFDictionary pathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x405590b00

Comment: It's a runtime error, so it won't show up at compile time. It looks like you're sending `pathExtension` to an `NSDictionary`; `pathExtension` is a method defined for `NSString`.

Comment: U mean to say there should be some editing to be done in my code n there is no issue with App Store???

Comment: Yes, it looks like a programming error.

Answer (score 2):

I've ran into this issue before. First, what's happening here is that the Apple provided command line tool which validates the binary is catching an exception when its doing its checks. The validator doesn't actually run your app, so any error probably isn't in any specific code file but one of the "metadata" files for your app.

Probably, the error is in your info.plist file. When it processes that, its expecting a string for a value, but is instead getting a dictionary from the plist.

When I ran into an issue it was an issue with the `CFBundleIcons` key in the info plist. The code change that fixed it is below.

From this:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon.png</string>
            <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

To This:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>icon@2x.png</string>
    <string>icon.png</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>icon@2x.png</string>
            <string>icon.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```